# Laravel carbon check if past date from table

Tags: php-carbon

So i want to get data from my API where datetime in the past,but when i tried this code.. its appear that i got data where ONLY DATE in the past not include the time

```
    $id_merchant = $request->input('id_merchant');
    
    $Promotion = DB::table('promotion')
        ->leftJoin('product', 'product.id', '=', 'promotion.id_product')
        ->where('promotion.id_merchant', '=', $id_merchant)
        ->whereDate('end_time','>=', Carbon::now())
        ->select('promotion.*','product.product_name','product.price','product.stock')
        ->get();
```

i see some people solve it with

> $end_time->isPast() function

but i dont know how to implement this in my case.
sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
->where('end_time', '>=', Carbon::now())
```

(whereDate filter the time)